# How to highlight Bash scripts in Vim?

Tags: linux, bash, vim, syntax-highlighting, vim-syntax-highlighting

My Vim editor auto highlights PHP files (`vim file.php`), HTML files (`vim file.html`) and so on.

But when I type: `vim file` and inside it write a Bash script, it doesn't highlight it.

How can I tell Vim to highlight it as a Bash script?

I start typing `#!/bin/bash` at the top of the file, but it doesn't make it work.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Are you correctly giving the shell script a `.sh` extension?  Vim's automatic syntax selection is almost completely based on file name (extension) detection.  If a file doesn't have a syntax set (or is the wrong syntax), Vim won't automatically change to the correct syntax just because you started typing a script in a given language.

As a temporary workaround, the command `:set syn=sh` will turn on shell-script syntax highlighting.

Comment: but the most scripts dont have a .sh extension? should i put it as a .sh extension just to make it work? is it best practice to name your scripts? and its bash...so its still .sh?

Comment: @ajsie: I'm not sure what scripts you're using, but most `bash` scripts I encounter do indeed have a `.sh` suffix.  To really specify *bash* as opposed to just `sh`, you would use the `#!/bin/bash` shebang line on a `.sh` file.

Comment: just type :set ft=sh and your good to go, OR, prefix your script with a modeline:  "# vim:ft=sh" without the quotes of course, AND, i suggest getting something better than the sh filetype highlighter for bash scripts because it does not recognize things properly, some examples are ${VAR: 1:2} substrings, ;& or ;;& <- end-of-case modifiers, and many of the bash-specific keywords are not recognized either. Of course, dont get one that is crappy because there ARE SOME BAD ONES circulating around out there, ive used a couple that were way worse than the sh.vim default.

Comment: If a file does not have an extension (as many shell scripts used as commands do) then Vim will look at the first line to see a shebang of either `#!/bin/sh` or `#!/bin/bash` to determine the file type either `ft=sh` or `ft=text` in the case no shebang exists.

Comment: @MarkRushakoff, giving bash scripts a `.sh` extension is in many circles considered poor form. See for instance the factoid bot used by the Freenode #bash channel's relevant entry: http://wooledge.org/~greybot/meta/.sh

Comment: ...to quote: "Don't use extensions for your scripts. Scripts define new commands that you can run, and commands are generally not given extensions. Do you run `ls.elf`? Also: bash scripts are *not* sh scripts (so don't use `.sh`) and the extension will only cause dependencies headaches if the script gets rewritten in another language. See http://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/documents/commandname-extensions-considered-harmful"

Comment: ...extensions on shell scripts are universally accepted as a Good Idea when a script is intended to be *sourced as a library* (just as one uses a `.py` extension for Python *modules* but not Python *scripts* located in the PATH) -- but in that case the extension should correctly reflect which shell the script can be correctly parsed by; `.sh` implies "compatible with all POSIX shells", which is not generally accurate for a *bash* script.

Comment: The `sh` syntax appears to highlight POSIX shell; it does not highlight Bash-specific syntax.

Answer (score 49):

The answers so far are correct that you can use the extension (like `.sh`) or a shebang line (like `#!/bin/bash`) to identify the file type. If you don't have one of those, you can still specify the file type manually by using a modeline comment at the top or bottom of your file.

For instance, if you want to identify a script without an extension as a shell script, you could add this comment to the top of your file:

```
# vim: set filetype=sh :
```

or

```
# vim: filetype=sh
```

That will tell vim to treat the file as a shell script. (You can set other things in the modeline, too. In vim type `:help modeline` for more info.)

Comment: Interestingly, in my environment, the final `:` makes this modeline work, whereas without the final `:`, this modeline doesn't register. The help documentation shows a form of a modeline that does not end in `:`.

Comment: That is interesting. The help documentation (with `:help modeline`) tells two differences: (1) The version with the final `:` "is compatible with some versions of Vi", and (2) without the final `:` you don't use the `set` keyword. Since you can put any text after the modeline, the final `:` works with or without the `set` keyword.

Comment: If the modeline seems to have no effect, try `set modeline` in `~/.vimrc`, see [this answer](http://superuser.com/q/323712/72223)

Comment: As I noted on the other answer that suggests this, `sh` appears to highlight POSIX shell, not bash. Notably, it flags valid bash syntax as errors, which is rather annoying.

Answer (score 28):

Actually syntax highlighting is a feature of vim not vi.
Try using vim command and then do

`:syntax on`.

Comment: For me too. You can add the line "syntax on" to your .vimrc file.

Comment: This was the solution for me on Mac OS X 10.10.3. Added a .vimrc file to my home directory using `vim ~/.vimrc` and adding `syntax on` to the file then closing with `:x`

Answer (score 24):

I came to this answer looking for specifically how to highlight **`bash`** syntax, not POSIX shell. Simply doing a `set ft=sh` (or equivalent) will result in the file being highlighted for POSIX shell, which leaves a lot of syntax that's valid in `bash` highlighted in red. To get bash highlighting:

```
" Set a variable on the buffer that tells the sh syntax highlighter
" that this is bash:
let b:is_bash = 1
" Set the filetype to sh
set ft=sh
```

Note that if your `ft` is already `sh`, you still need the `set` command; otherwise the `let` doesn't take effect immediately.

You can make this a global default by making the variable global, i.e., `let g:is_bash = 1`.

`:help ft-sh-syntax` is the manual page I had to find; it explains this, and how to trigger highlighting of other flavors of shell.

Comment: Some versions of the `sh` syntax highlighter even mark valid posix sh code as invalid (e.g. `$(subshell)`) - this corrects that too. Thanks.

Comment: This is exactly what I came here looking for, and it works perfectly. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 17):

Vim can also detect file types by inspecting their contents (like for example if the first line contains a bash shebang), here is a quote from `filetype.txt` help file:

**If your filetype can only be detected by inspecting the contents of the file**

Create your user runtime directory.  You would normally use the first item of the 'runtimepath' option.  Example for Unix:

```
:!mkdir ~/.vim
```

Create a vim script file for doing this.  Example:

```
if did_filetype()   " filetype already set..
    finish      " ..don't do these checks
endif
if getline(1) =~ '^#!.*\<mine\>'
    setfiletype mine
elseif getline(1) =~? '\<drawing\>'
    setfiletype drawing
endif
```

See $VIMRUNTIME/scripts.vim for more examples.
Write this file as "scripts.vim" in your user runtime directory.  For
example, for Unix:

```
:w ~/.vim/scripts.vim
```

The detection will work right away, no need to restart Vim.

Your scripts.vim is loaded before the default checks for file types, which
means that your rules override the default rules in
$VIMRUNTIME/scripts.vim.

Comment: I've tried both putting this in the .vimrc and .vim/scripts.vim, but neither has worked. It only works if I manually type in the commands once I've started vim. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Eddy Probably you need `set modeline` in `~/.vimrc`, see [this answer](http://superuser.com/q/323712/72223)

Answer (score 10):

Vim can detect the file type reading the first line. Add the following line as first line.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
```

Comment: looks like this was fixed.  This is the best answer IMHO.

Answer (score 4):

For those who have a variant of this question i.e. how to enable syntax highlighting on bash files without `.sh` extension automatically when opened...

Add `filetype on` in your `.vimrc`. This enables file type detection by also considering the file's contents. For example, bash scripts will be set to `sh` file-type. However, typing the `#!` won't trigger file type detection on a new file created with vim and you will need to use `set ft=sh` in that case.   For more [info](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/filetype.html), type `:h filetype` in vim.

As mentioned in the comments, you will need to use this in conjuction with `syntax enable` to turn on highlighting.

Or you could use `:filetype detect`.
From the doc:

> Use this if you started with an empty file and typed text that makes
>   it possible to detect the file type. For example, when you entered
>   this in a    shell script: "#!/bin/csh".

Comment: The command is `filetype on`, without set, and you also need `syntax enable` to turn on highlighting.

Answer (score 2):

Once you add the shebang at the top of the file, save it and reload it (e.g. `:w|e`) and syntax coloring can kick in.

See also [Vim inconsistently syntax highlighting bash files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7450395/vim-inconsistently-syntax-highlighting-bash-files), the accepted answer may help as well.

Answer (score 1):

To toggle syntax highlight on/off while you're inside the editor.

Turn on

```
:syntax on
```

Turn off

```
:syntax off
```

Run this to always have syntax highlighting on when opening vim.

```bash
echo ":syntax on" >> ~/.vimrc
```

Answer (score 0):

vim already recognizes many file types by default. Most of them work by file extensions, but in a case like this, vim will also analyze the content of the file to guess the correct type.

vim sets the filetype for specific file names like `.bashrc`, `.tcshrc`, etc. automatically. But a file with a `.sh` extension will be recognized as either csh, ksh or bash script. To determine what kind of script this is exactly, vim reads the first line of the file to look at the #! line.

If the first line contains the word `bash`, the file is identified as a bash script. Usually you see `#!/bin/bash` if the script is meant to be executed directly, but for a shell configuration file using a simple `# bash` would work as well.

If you want to look at the details, this is implemented in `$VIMRUNTIME/filetype.vim`.

Comment: Uhm, actually I wanted to post this somewhere else. But I guess the answer fits here as well :-)

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way to get syntax highlighting on a new file, is to just reload it after writing the shebang line. A simple `:w` `:e` will write out the file, reload it, and interprete the shebang line you have just written to provide you with the appropriate syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 0):

If you already know the file-type before opening the script or if you're creating a new script without an extension which is common, you can pass it to vim on the command-line like so:

```
vim -c 'setfiletype sh' path/to/script
vim -c 'setfiletype python' path/to/script
```

Answer (score -1):

When you create a new file, only the filename detection comes into play; content detection (`#!/bin/bash`) doesn't apply if you type it after creating a new buffer.

The sensible thing is to just do `:set ft=bash` the first time around, and the *next* time you edit it, the `#!/bin/bash` will set the right filetype automatically.

Comment: At my side `ft=bash` needs to read `ft=sh`.  Also I needed `set modeline` in `~/.vimrc` to make it work, see [this answer](http://superuser.com/q/323712/72223)