# Vim inconsistently syntax highlighting bash files

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, vim-syntax-highlighting

When I open some bash script files with vim it sometimes identifies them as `conf` files, that's okay, I can just correct that by setting the filetype to `sh` with `:setf sh`.

That great, except I've noticed that this doesn't fix things entirely:

[image: Two files side-by-side with different highlighting]

Notice that `shopt` is properly highlighted on the left, but not on the right, where I manually set the filetype to `sh`.

This means that when a file is identified as `bash` or `sh` by vim, it sets the filetype to `sh` but then does some extra steps that I'm not doing when I set the filetype manually.

Any one know what that might be, and how I could fix it?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

vim already recognizes many file types by default. Most of them work by file extensions, but in a case like this, vim will also analyze the content of the file to guess the correct type.

vim sets the filetype for specific file names like `.bashrc`, `.tcshrc`, etc. automatically. But a file with a `.sh` extension will be recognized as either csh, ksh or bash script. To determine what kind of script this is exactly, vim reads the first line of the file to look at the #! line.

If the first line contains the word `bash`, the file is identified as a bash script. Usually you see `#!/bin/bash` if the script is meant to be executed directly, for some other shell configuration file you should use the file extensions `.bash`.

The help in vim explains this as well at `:help ft-bash-syntax`. You can also use `let g:is_bash=1` in your .vimrc to make bash syntax highlighting the default for all files with `filetype=sh`. If you want to look at the details, this is implemented in `$VIMRUNTIME/filetype.vim`.

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer because it nicely explains the why, as well as providing a perfectly reasonable solution. I've also added an answer detailing my own solution.

Comment: **_Ugh_.** While the introductory synopsis is helpful, the presented solution (e.g., `let g:is_bash=1` in `.vimrc`) is unhelpful. Why? Because doing so coerces non-Bash shell script buffers (e.g., Bourne, Korn) to use Bash-specific syntax highlighting. Consider [Tim Friske](https://stackoverflow.com/users/881945/tim-friske)'s [excellent solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13445254/2809027) instead.

Comment: @CecilCurry That is exactly why I added the fair warning that this affects every file with `filetype=sh`. Actually, I just reproduced what `:help ft-bash-syntax` recommends to add to your `.vimrc` to make this the global default. It will not force this syntax for all shell files. A more specific shebang like `#!/bin/ksh` will still override this *default* choice, so I cannot reproduce your concern.

Answer (score 9):

It turns out that `syntax/sh.vim` includes specific highlighting for **Korn**, **Bash** and **sh**, you just have to tell it which you're using. This is done with `b:is_kornshell`, `b:is_bash` and `b:is_sh` respectively.

Depending on the situation I figure I'll use the following:

#### ftdetect/bash.vim:

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile *bash* let g:is_bash=1
au BufRead,BufNewFile *bash* setf sh
```

#### Modeline:

```
# vim:let g:is_bash=1:set filetype=sh:
```

#### Key Mapping

```
nmap <silent> <leader>b :let g:is_bash=1<cr> :setf sh<cr>
```

Comment: +1 Sweet! The modeline approach would be my favorite. (If I cared anough about such minor deviations :))

Comment: @Peter Coulton: Didn't you mean to set the `b:is_bash` variable local to the buffer instead of the `g:is_bash` variable global. At least your code snippet doesn't reflect this circumstance. Also you could concatenate the two `au` commands by ending the first with `let b:is_bash = 1 | setfiletype sh`.

Comment: I don't see the benefit of setting the global every time you load a file with 'bash' in its filename vs. just setting it once in your `.vimrc` and being done with it.

Comment: Unfortunately for this use case, it is not possible to set a variable in a modeline.

Comment: **Non-ideal.** Globally enabling `g:is_bash=1` enables Bash-specific syntax highlighting for *all* non-Bash shell script buffers (e.g., Bourne, Korn) – which is bad. Locally enabling `b:is_bash=1` is vastly preferable. Likewise, per-filetype `ftdetect/` files have largely been obsoleted by a single `filetype.vim` file unifying *all* filetype detection. For a solution that addresses both, see [Tim Friske](https://stackoverflow.com/users/881945/tim-friske)'s [excellent solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13445254/2809027).

Comment: @Peter-Coulton I'm using vim v8.1 but your modeline returns an error : `Error detected while processing modelines:
line    1:
E518: Unknown option: let`

Answer (score 4):

Similar to Peter Coulton's solution and documented as well as an alternative in the section "new-filetype" of the "filetype" Vim help the `~/.vim/filetype.vim` file could contain the following code:

```
if exists("did_load_filetypes")
  finish
endif

augroup filetypedetect
  au! BufRead,BufNewFile *bash* let b:is_bash = 1 | setfiletype sh
augroup END
```

This approach has the following implications:

1. There is one `~/.vim/filetype.vim` file instead of one for each file type under the `~/.vim/ftdetect` directory.
2. The `b:is_bash` variable is set local to the buffer as opposed to global by referring to it as `g:is_bash`.

Answer (score 3):

Try viewing the effective syntax setting

```
:windo echo b:current_syntax
```

(I kind of expect the first window to say `bash`, and the second to say `sh`...?)

Also try mucking with the synatx synchronisation:

```
:windo syn sync fromstart
:windo syn sync minlines=300
```

In general

```
:he syn-sync
```

for more information

---

### PS.

A long shot, but some other highlighting might be interfering:

```
:windo se @/=''
:match none
:2match none
:3match none
```