# Vi syntax-highlighting after executing vi within bash script

Tags: bash, syntax-highlighting, vi

I created this Stackoverflow account only for asking this question:

Is there a way to tell Vi to do syntax-highlighting when executing it from within a script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
vi /path/to/script.sh
```

I was trying things like [this](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/6936/how-can-i-select-a-syntax-highlighting-at-the-shell-command-line) and other stuff like `sudo su -`  in order to reset the environment, but nothing worked..

Any chance a to make it work(preferably without editing the .vimrc)?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You can run a command when you launch vi after the file is loaded:

`vi -c "syntax on" /path/to/script.sh`

That should turn on syntax highlighting

Comment: That didn't work :/

Comment: What happens ? Can you provide more information on how you did it ?

Comment: I tried multiple ways e.g.[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576687/how-to-highlight-bash-scripts-in-vim)):

`#!/bin/bash
vi -c "syntax on" script.sh`

`#!/bin/bash
vi -c "syntax on" -R +'setf bash' scripts.sh`

`#!/bin/bash
echo "vi script.sh" 0> `tty` # to get it forwardet to another terminal (plan was to exit the script and execute it "fresh" after the script exits`

As you can see the way is always the same: Start a Script -> run vi script.sh within it. But the result is always without syntax highlighting

Comment: This works perfectly for me:

`vi +"syntax on" +"set ft=python" run.sh`

Comment: Didn't work, too.. you ran that command from within a script or directly from cli?

Comment: From within a script as per your question...

Comment: Nevermind. I was just wondering since it seems to be so easy, regarding your answer.

I was trying different terminal-clients too (xfterm and the gnome3-client) with same result ..

Answer (score 0):

On most Unix systems, vi is not vi itself, but a symlink to /etc/alternatives/vi, which itself is a symlink to a vi-alike editor. You can find out which editor that is with the command
`ls -l /etc/alternatives/vi`.
Fabio Almeida clearly has vim, which has syntax highlighting, but you might have an editor like nvi, which doesn't. To use it, you would have to install a different editor (like vim).